# I migrate a website with a stripe payment : error 500 on charge.php?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I migrate a website with a stripe payment on checkout.js on it. When I migrate all the data, and import the database, everything work except the payment. 
When I click on PAY, I have an error 500 on charge.php. 
Do you know what I've miss to change on the configuration ?

I've tried to the change on another adress, I put SSL, I try on test mode without SLL, I check the backoffice of Stripe with nothing to configure there.

I always had an Error 500 in place to redirect to the Thank You page.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the URL that you're seeing a 500 error from? If it's one of Stripe's API servers, I'd recommend [contacting support directly](https://www.stripe.com/contact) as they can tell you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: No It's from my side, https://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/charge.php. 

My original website work perfectily in the same configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My charge.php was corrupted, it's why I have an 500 error. Maybe during the migration this particular file had had a problem. Problem solve !